# Is it possible to put Android ActionBar on the bottom?

Tags: android-actionbar, android, xoom

i'm developing an application to an Android Tablet (XOOM), and i would like to know if it is possile to put the action bar on the bottom of the screen, instead of the top (which is the default option).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you're getting your ActionBar in an Activity you could just add this android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"  to your manifest for that specific Activity.

That worked for me :)

Comment: hi thanx it is working fine in potrait mode but it is not working on tab and device in landscape mode plz give me solution...

Comment: yes,it wont work in landscape mode.There is no such provision in android,we need to do some hack or mannual code.Plz try code I have given above it will work for landscape too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible like this,try this.

```
 public void setActionBArAtBottom(View layoutView, Intent intent,
            Context context, ContentValues componentIds) throws Exception {
        if (componentIds != null) {
            setValues(componentIds);
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("Provide appropriate information to set ActionBar at bottom");
            try {
                throw new UnsufficientResourcesException();
            } catch (UnsufficientResourcesException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // getting the parent of screen..actually this is the child of root
        // parent...
        ViewGroup screenParent = (ViewGroup) layoutView.getParent().getParent();
        // now getting actionbarview...as follows...
        View actionBArView = ((ViewGroup) screenParent.getChildAt(0))
                .getChildAt(0);
        // now getting framelayout that is custom layout to display actionbar at
        // the bottom...
        FrameLayout customActionBarFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) layoutView
                .findViewById(BOTTOM_ACTION_BAR_LAYOUT_ID);
        // now remove actionbarView from its parent view...
        ViewGroup actionBarViewParent = removeFromParent(actionBArView);
        removeTitleAndIcon((ViewGroup) actionBArView);
        // now setting actionbar view to the framlayout...
        customActionBarFrameLayout.addView(actionBArView);

        // get the custombar layout....
        View customTitleBarLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                NEW_TITLE_BAR_LAYOUT, null);
        // setting icon to titile bar...
        ((ImageView) customTitleBarLayout.findViewById(NEW_TITLE_ICON__ID))
                .setImageDrawable(getActivityIcon(intent, context));
        // setting title...
        ((TextView) customTitleBarLayout.findViewById(NEW_TITLE_ID))
                .setText(((SherlockActivity) context).getTitle());
        // now set this layout to
        actionBarViewParent.addView(customTitleBarLayout);

    }

    // method use to remove child from its parent...
    private ViewGroup removeFromParent(View child) {
        // removing child...
        ViewGroup parentGroup = (ViewGroup) child.getParent();
        parentGroup.removeView(child);
        return parentGroup;
    }

    // this method will set application icon to custom title bar layout...
    private Drawable getActivityIcon(Intent intent, Context context) {
        // getting the current activity icon set...
        Drawable drawable = null;
        try {
            drawable = context.getPackageManager().getActivityIcon(intent);
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return drawable;
    }

    // remove title and icon from bottombar...
    private void removeTitleAndIcon(ViewGroup actionBarViewGroup) {
        actionBarViewGroup.removeAllViews();
    }

    private void setValues(ContentValues contentValues) throws Exception {
        try {
            BOTTOM_ACTION_BAR_LAYOUT_ID = contentValues
                    .getAsInteger(BOTTOM_ACTION_BAR_FRAME_LAYOUT_ID);
            NEW_TITLE_BAR_LAYOUT = contentValues
                    .getAsInteger(NEW_TITLE_BAR_LAYOUT_ID);
            NEW_TITLE_ICON__ID = contentValues
                    .getAsInteger(NEW_TITLE_ICON_IMAGEVIEW_ID);
            NEW_TITLE_ID = contentValues.getAsInteger(NEW_TITLE_VIEW_ID);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new UnsufficientResourcesException();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try this above code to get actionbar at the bottom for any api level and even in landscape mode also...