# diference in showing app on physical device and emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

My problem is that I have an app with action bar menu. The app works fine on the emulator, everything is shown, but when I'm debugging it on physical device, I can't see action bar with buttons. I have added action bar with support library. `MinSdkVer` of app is `8`. My phone has  android version `2.3.6`, so version shouldn't make any problems. I don't know what can be done to make it work.

Comment: Which support library have you added?

Comment: You are using `appcompat v7 support library` ?

Comment: yeah, this same.  v7 appcompat library

Comment: whats your emulator api action bar needs api 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your project with the appcompat v7 support library by following the instructions in the Support Library Setup.

Once your project is set up with the support library, here's how to add the action bar:

1. Create your activity by extending ActionBarActivity.
2. Use (or extend) one of the Theme.AppCompat themes for your activity. For example:
3. Now your activity includes the action bar when running on Android 2.1 (API level 7) or higher.

Comment: yeah, thx it works. I have one more question, haw can I put my action bar on the bottom of screen, because  "android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" this line in manifest doesn't work now.

Comment: ok, I find it here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html           under the paragraph "Using Split Action Bar" I post it, maybe somebody will need it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039034/is-it-possible-to-put-android-actionbar-on-the-bottom

Answer (score 0):

check your emulator version it might be above 3.0 and if you run app in emulator with version below 3.0 you will get the same buttons you have watched in your device....

the solution is you have to use support library concept shown in following links,

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

http://tekeye.biz/2012/android-support-library-samples

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/